# let $f: A\subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ Now : Can we find all the local extremum points of the function Using Derivative.?

Tags: calculus

let $f: A\subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ 
Now :
Can we find all the  local extremum points of the function with only Using Derivative.?

Comment: Obvisouly no if it happens that $f$ is not differentiable...

Comment: Trivial remark : $f$ needs to be at least differentiable. Otherwise $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$...

Comment: it would be nice if you clarify your assumptions: $A$ arbitrary, bounded, connected, open? $f$ continuous, differentiable, weak differentiable...?

Comment: Also, if $A=\{0\}$ there's no notion of derivative of $f$ there, but $\{0\}$ is a local minimum.

Comment: How about finding the local extremum of $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=|x|$.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek . $A=\text{arbitrary subset }$

Comment: How about $A=\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: For the case when $A=\Bbb Q$ it does not even make sense talking about continuity as no point of $A$ is a limit point, which is in fact a foremost criteria when discussing limits or continuity wrt the usual metric